# How do I stop opening tex files of particular portion when I scroll the embedded PDF in TeXStudio?

Tags: texstudio

This is happening in TeXStudio 2.10.8. I compile and view the PDF in the embedded PDF viewer. Whenever I scroll the embedded PDF, relevant section's .tex files are opened in the left. I want to stop opening those section's .tex files, as I scroll through the PDF file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is usually controlled by a toggle icon in the viewer section

Note that other viewer sync settings may not always be visible whilst viewer is imbedded and may need to be "windowed" so you can access Configure > Scrolling follows cursor or Ignore for synchronization

[image]

```
The toggles are at the bottom of the viewer ^^
```